# Delay-off circuit for h-bridge motor control

Tags: arduino, pwm, timer, coil

I'm looking for the easiest way to generate a variable PWM signal (set by hardware) without a microcontroller for a set amount of time when a microcontroller is turned off.

The H-bridge (image below) is driving a 12VDC fan that is sitting directly underneath about ~1,200W of heating coils in a coffee roaster, heating the air up to ~500C. If the power is cut to the arduino, I would like the fan to be driven with a PWM signal (~50% - 70% duty cycle) for ~3 to ~10 seconds, so that it isn't heat soaking into the plastic fan blade below it.

[image: H-Bridge]

I'm not sure what 'CT' and 'VT' are, I'm assuming this dual motor driver is controlled by the 'LPWM' and 'RPWM' and I'd just use a single input / single output for the fan.

Can I use something like a 555 timer to generate the PWM signal, and then use a resistor between that and the Arduino pin tied directly to the H-Bridge input, so that when the arduino is powered off and enters high-impedence mode, the ~50%-70% duty cycle signal takes over, but when it is powered on and driving the pin, it is irrelevant?

How can I also time this out after a set period after the arduino has lost power? I'm looking to do this safety feature without adding a second microcontroller, if possible.

Comment: Just can't see the point. If you have power (mains) to run the fan (and the micro) just do not switch off Arduino abruptly, go thru a software power down sequence 3mins @ 50% or whatever required. Otherwise if don't have power for the micro you don't have for the fan too, you will have to replace melted down blades.

Comment: Also, a H bridge is overkill for a simple fan (unless you need to reverse the motor, which you don't in this case). A single transistor paired with a flyback diode would be simpler and cheaper.

Comment: If the power is cut to the Arduino is also cut to the fan, or not? If not, don't cut the power to the Arduino, why would you do that?

Comment: I have a power switch on the 5v line to the Arduino, though I suppose I could have the Arduino on constantly and just read the state of the switch as a soft-power button. The H-Bridge may be overkill, but that's what makes projects exciting for me, and I might go to a 3A fan and want to variable drive it, which means transistor + big heat sink, or just a $5 H-Bridge that has one and other circuitry.

Comment: So no, turning off the switch or uploading a new sketch only turns off the Arduino, not the mains or 12VDC power. Given that you aren't convinced on the point, is this possible with very few components?

Comment: @Ehryk Your requirement for controlling the speed of the fan doesn't rule out a single transistor drive. You can pulse-width modulate the single transistor to control the fan speed, just like you can PWM a H-bridge. You don't need a heat sink for just 3A at 12 V if you select the transitor appropriately; a low Rdson MOSFET like the common [RFP30N06](https://www.sparkfun.com/datasheets/Components/General/RFP30N06LE.pdf) won't heat up significantly even when driven from a microcontroller pin at 5 V

Comment: How I drive the fan, and my desire for overkill doesn't alter the question of how to 1) generate a given duty cycle PWM signal without a microcontroller, 2) have it time out after a set duration, and 3) union it with the microcontroller output with the microcontroller taking precedence.

Comment: 1) a 555 timer 2) a second 555 timer in monostable mode 3) a digital multiplexer, either a dedicated chip or one [made from a quad NAND gate](http://www.electronics-tutorials.ws/combination/multiplexer2.gif?x98918). You can't use simple diode or resistor "logic" as opposed to the MUX as the 555 would backfeed power into the arduino trough the PWM output and power it up trough the internal ESD protection diodes. Personally I'd rethink the system architecture, it makes no sense to add that much complexity when you could solve the problem in software.

Comment: Why can't two diodes prevent backfeed, or a resistor be selected if a high enough value that cannot power the Arduino? Would you be willing to draw that circuit up and post it as an answer so I can accept it?